# Call a void* as a function without declaring a function pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, void

I've searched but couldn't find any results (my terminology may be off) so forgive me if this has been asked before.

I was wondering if there is an easy way to call a `void*` as a function in C without first declaring a function pointer and then assigning the function pointer the address;

ie. assuming the function to be called is type `void(void)`

```
void *ptr;
ptr = <some address>;
((void*())ptr)(); /* call ptr as function here */
```

with the above code, I get *error C2066: cast to function type is illegal* in VC2008

If this is possible, how would the syntax differ for functions with return types and multiple parameters?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your cast should be:

```
((void (*)(void)) ptr)();
```

In general, this can be made simpler by creating a `typedef` for the function pointer type:

```
typedef void (*func_type)(void);
((func_type) ptr)();
```

I should, however, point out that casting an ordinary pointer (pointer to object) to or from a function pointer is not strictly legal in standard C (although it is a common extension).

Answer (score 13):

I get awfully confused when casting to function types. It's easier and more readable to typedef the function pointer type:

```
void *ptr = ...;
typedef void (*void_f)(void);
((void_f)ptr)();
```

Answer (score 12):

In C++: `reinterpret_cast< void(*)() > (ptr) ()`

The use of `reinterpret_cast` saves you a set of confusing parentheses, and the `< >` clearly sets the type apart from the call itself.