# C++ variable type

Tags: c++

I have a function which takes two variables:

```
call((void**) &var, float);
call((void**) &var, int);
call((void**) &var, string);
```

Now I want to create a function to call that special function:

```
function start_call(/*what to put here?*/)
{
    call((void**) &var1, float);
    call((void**) &var2, int);
    call((void**) &var3, string);
     //code
}
```

So, what to put in the "what to put here?" place, in order for the function to accep any variable?

I tried my berst to explain it...

Comment: How do you pass a *type* as an argument to a function?

Comment: Why not use templates?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg by using a language other than c++, for one

Comment: Have you looked at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635715/call-a-void-as-a-function-without-declaring-a-function-pointer or this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-class-methods-via-a-function-pointer

Comment: giving up on this question

Comment: Can you show how you declare `call`, and exactly what you'd like `start_call` to look like?

Comment: I don't know how to declare call. start_call must take one variable. That variable should be any type. Then, on the function I want to find out the variable type.

Comment: @SkyRipper It might be better for you to describe the problem you're trying to solve, instead of asking us how to implement what you think might be a solution.

Comment: Here is a function used in nVidia CUDA: cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_A, N * sizeof(float)); I want to call that function from another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a template:

```
template <class T> start_call(T in);
```

Comment: No problem :) templates are a very powerful feature of C++.